# Caddy configuration for Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite, caddy, caddyfile

I'm trying to setup a Wordpress website with multisite:

- example.com
- example.com/fr

With the following Caddyfile:

```
example.com:80 {
    redir https://www.example.com{uri}
}

www.example.com:80 {
    root /app/public
    gzip

    fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:9000 {
        ext .php
        split .php
        index index.php
    }

    rewrite {
        regexp ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*)
        to {path} {path}/ {1}
    }

    rewrite {
        regexp ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$
        to {path} {path}/ {1}
    }

    rewrite {
        if {path} not_match ^\/wp-admin
        to {path} {path}/ /index.php?_url={uri}
    }

    log stdout
    startup /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 -F -O &
}
```

When I reach `/fr/wp-admin/`, I get a 301 to `/wp-admin/`.

Does anybody know how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

This caddy config works for me. Hope this helps.

```
rewrite {
    regexp ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*)
    to {2}
}

rewrite {
    regexp ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php)
    to {2}
}

rewrite {
    if {path} not_match ^\/wp-admin
    to {path} {path}/ /index.php?{query}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you indicated with:

```
rewrite {
    regexp ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*)
    to {path} {path}/ {1}
}
```

Which in your case, with the request `/fr/wp-admin/` will try to serve:

1. `{path}` = `/fr/wp-admin/`
2. `{path}/` = `/fr/wp-admin/`
3. `{1}` = `/wp-admin/`, which is the first block captured in your parenthesis

Meaning Caddy doesn't find the admin under `/fr`, or isn't redirected property afterward, depending on what you aim.